# ruby hours and minutes

Tags: ruby, time, duration

I need to store a time log for employees. We need to know that they spent, for example, 20 minutes working on project A and 1 hr 30 minutes working on project B.

Before I run a migration, I'd like to understand what the best practice is for storing this sort of information. we don't need to know anything about date or time so I don't want to get into date / time calculations of duration. Just a user-entered hours and minutes. However, we will certainly have to do calculations at some point. So the employee mentioned above did a total of 1hr 50 minutes.

I was going to create 2 integer fields. One for the hours and one for the minutes, and deal with the calculations later. Does that make sense, or am I making a mistake at the first hurdle?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just store minutes? Or seconds, etc, depending on how you'll need to use the data later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the duration in seconds as an integer value.

You can use the [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem if you want to easily parse human input to actual durations, for example to convert "1 hour and 40 minutes" to 100 minutes or 6000 seconds.

Comment: This seems reasonable - can the conversion work the other way - so if I have the users enter 1 hr and 20 minutes can I convert that into seconds?

Comment: @GarethBurrows From hours to seconds is `* 3600` and from minutes to seconds is `* 60`, no library needed for that right :)?

Answer (score 0):

No Ruby magic for your specific purposes, just store your time in minutes (integer).

So you will have something like

```
@employee.time_spent_on_project_a = params[:hour]*60 + params[:minute]
```

and store it as an integer field

**However**, I have to mention that Ruby makes dealing with dates/times very easy. If you rather want to record the time than have input fields, you will be able to do something like:

```
@start_time = Time.now
# ...
@end_time = Time.now
```

and then you can just save your value as `@end_time - @start_time` (as a decimal, in seconds). So you might want to reconsider... or not. Depending on how much precision you want.

Comment: Your first solution was precisely how I was going to handle it!

Comment: @GarethBurrows remember also to think about future applications you might want to achieve. If you are logging employee activity, it might be a good idea to rather store two database fields, one for start time and one for end time - both datetime fields.